# How to close a full screen iframe?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, iframe

I've a wordpress site which load the content of a post in one iframe with position fixed and width and height 100%. This is hover all website…

I've a CLOSE button; how to tell the button to hide the iframe and show the content under it?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Thanks

```
<h2><a class="trick" rel="<?php the_permalink() ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
  $(".trick").click(function(){
    var post_link = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#frame").attr("url", post_link);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: we'll forgive if you show us some code

Comment: @LucaFrankGuarini please update your question instead of adding a comment, it will be easier for us to read

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close your iframe from a button in your iframe you will need something like this:

```
<button onclick="parent.window.location.hash ='close'">close</button>
```

This will change the ref in your url. ex: yourwebiste.com/yourpage.php#close 
Then you will need to check when this reference is called with something like this (in the parent file):

```
    var close_iframe = false;

setInterval(function(){

    if(!close_iframe){

        hash_val = window.location.hash;

        if (hash_arr[0] == "#close"){

            $(#iframe_id).hide();
            close_iframe = true;

        }
    }

  }, 100);
```

Hope I was clear enough and it helps you, sorry , this is my first answer hehe.

Comment: Thank you.. the first line code works. The #close is added to the url. Where have I to insert the second part?